# Account freeze for some seconds

Tags: c#, forms, window

Hi I have login system similar app in c# windows form. when user enters 3 times wrong details a message comes and say ACCOUNT LOCKED. Is there any trick/way to freeze the account of that user for few seconds?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Dictionary providing the **username** and the **time** when he was blocked. e.g.:

```
private Dictionary<string, DateTime> blockedUsers;
```

Before log in, you will verify if the current user exists in "blockedUsers", if true, then you must compare the current time and the time stored in the list for that specific user. If it is between the range of 30 secs, you may cancel the login showing an error. Otherwise, you will remove this user from the block list. Something like this:

```
        // Checks if the user exists in the blockedUsers.
        if (blockedUsers.ContainsKey(userName))
        {
            // If so, then gets the difference between when he was blocked and now.
            var diffInSeconds = (DateTime.Now - blockedUsers[userName]).TotalSeconds;
            // If the difference is smaller than 30, prevent him from loggin.
            if (diffInSeconds < 30)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, but your user has been temporary blocked from loggin. Try later.");
                return;
            }
            // If the diff is greater than 30, then there is no reason to keep him in blocked list.
            else
            {
                blockedUsers.Remove(userName);
            }
        }
```

Other thing you have to do is: if "wrongAttempts" is 3, then you add it in the "blockedUsers", if he try to log in again in 30 secs, he'll be blocked by the fist verification.

```
        if (wrongAttempts >= 3)
        {
            blockedUsers.Add(userName, DateTime.Now);
        }
```

That's it. Hope it may help you!

Comment: Thank You everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to freeze an account. You can set up a permissions list. Inside the permissions list you could set a token and increment it every time someone tries to login. If the value of the token is in excess of some value the user can't log in for sometime frame as determined by a `DateTime`setting.

What have you tried if anything? Do you have any code you can share so the users can understand the direction you wish to go in?

Comment: I tried something like if(correct){proceed} else {wrongAttempt++} if (wrongAttempts==3){Console.WriteLine ("Account Lock")}.

Kindly explain me the way I can replace Account Locked with 30sec freeze time of app or user account.

Comment: FelipeKunzler has a great start for you. I would start there and check back if you need more assistance.